Is there an available source that evaluates or ranks the credibility of newspapers?

Iran’s Leader Orders Attack on Israel for Haniyeh Killing, Officials Say

This is the headline of the New York Times page  [7/31/2024]. The article is based on the account of three Iranian officials who's identity is not revealed because they were not authorized to speak publicly, as the article claims.
However the U.K. newspaper The Telegraph recently published a fabricated article claiming that whistleblowers informed the newspaper that Hezbollah was using Beirut International Airport to store a large stockpile of missiles, which was refuted by local authorities by showing local and foreign officials along with reporters all divisions of the airport where there were no such weapons.
The Telegraph of course did not reveal the names of the alleged whistleblowers, and now The New York Times bases its article on anonymous officials. So, if one wants to check the credibility of a newspaper, how could it be done?
Is there an available source that evaluates or ranks the credibility of newspapers?

While this is useful to know it really isn't about politics or governments, not to mention you then have to decide how credible the person doing the credibility checks/ranking is.

I personally ran into an older [AP] story sourced to 6 (!!) supposed Iranian officials, which however doesn't seem to hold much water. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57007/did-iran-send-400-ballistic-missiles-to-russia I suspect western newspapers are rather easy to disinfo by Iranians [on topics like these], because of the unfamiliarity. OTOH the Iranian government itself is rather byzantine with competing factions, multiple army-like organizations etc.

Finally, on some topics like "we're gonna send ballistic missiles to Russia", or "take revenge for the killing of X", such promises/orders can be easily countermanded, so the reporting and the source[s] might actually have been truthful at the time, but then some higher-up leader changed his mind... and so [promised] stuff didn't happen. (In the case of Haniyeh, it's rather early to tell if they'll do something or not, of course. They might feel that despite the killing happening in Iran, revenge should be carried out by Hamas.)

mediabiasfactcheck.com is a quick and dirty way to check.  I am not entirely sure it doesn't privilege mainstream left/right center sources, as opposed to more extreme right or extreme left and I am also unsure about it's exact methodology but its my lazy-man's way to check sources I have no other acquaintance with.  It rates, separately, on bias (left or right) and accuracy-vs-failed fact checks.  FWIW, Iran ordering a revenge of sorts seems well within its expected response parameters.

"Is there an available source that evaluates or ranks the credibility of newspapers?" This would surely be a Herculean task, with thousands of people needed for that with access to the ground truth. And who would pay for that or being interested in that. My gut feeling tells me that it's impossible to achieve that currently. Also I don't understand the example. Could you clarify what is credible or not credible about the headline? Also there are other dimensions like bias, ...

FWIW the MediaBiasFactCheck evaluation of the Telegraph is "Overall, we rate The Telegraph Right Biased based on story selection that strongly favors the right and Mixed for factual reporting due to poor sourcing of information and some failed fact checks" - https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/daily-telegraph/


Is there an available source that evaluates or ranks the credibility
of newspapers?

There are such rankings and the New York Times has historically been at or near the top of the list. Of course, the issue with any ranking of credibility is whether the person making the ranking is credible.
The New York Times is among the list of recommended sources for speech and debate competitions, for example. Survey measures of credibility are a function of partisan basis on the part of the people being surveyed and familiarity, but the New York Times still has majority support and is in the middle of the pack of mainstream media sources. The Pew data from the year 2009, in the second link in this paragraph, showing this partisan divide in trust of media sources, is as follows:

Simply put, Republicans tend to trust Fox News and the Wall Street Journal, which are conservative leaning news sources, while Democrats tend to be more trusting of all other media sources. Many people surveyed are also less familiar with more high brow news sources like the New York Times, Wall Street Journal, and National Public Radio, than they are with TV news sources that have a less sophisticated audience and tell stories at a lower reading comprehension level that assumes less general knowledge.
A well known media bias and credibility ranking firm places the New York Times as mildly left leaning but close to the top in credibility. (For what it is worth, I am not a huge fan of this ranking firm because it inaccurately conflates accuracy and having a political leaning even though it purports to treat these two matters independently, with not a single significant outlier from its trend line linking political leaning and accuracy when I am personally aware of several such examples, and because it gives Fox News far more credit for accuracy than it deserves in the face of a mountain of evidence to the contrary.)
Another ranking group, Allsides, ranks bias but not credibility and states that the New York Times leans left in its news reporting but if more left leaning in its opinion content.
Forbes magazine ranks the 10 large journalistic brands where you can most often find real, reported facts, and the New York Times as the most factually accurate source of news in the entire United States. The description of its #1 entry in the list states:

This is the most influential newspaper in the U.S. in my view. Its
editorial page and some of its news coverage take a left-leaning,
progressive view of the world. But the NYT also hews to ethical
standards of reporting and the classic elements of journalism in
America. That's what helps the NYT remain, arguably, the
agenda-setting news organization in America. It is a leader in
business, politics and culture coverage.

The author of the Forbes piece, who is a college professor of journalism disclosed, however, that:

Earlier in my career, I interned at the Associated Press and the
Washington Post. I worked as a staff writer at the Wall Street Journal
between 2001-2011. I have also published free-lance articles in the
Post, the New York Times and the New Yorker (website) as well as some
of the publications listed in the runner up lists.

Many of these rankings are U.S.-centric and don't rank the conservative leaning Telegraph newspaper in the U.K., but it is widely known to be a reasonably credible and accurate source of news. It is the second highest circulation newspaper in the U.K. after the Times that is not a "tabloid" (the Sun and the Daily Mail are U.K. tabloids with higher circulation).
There is a division in the newspaper industry between traditional newspapers and "tabloid" newspapers whose journalistic standard and ethics are impugned with the epithet "tabloid journalism". But neither the New York Times nor the Telegraph are consider tabloids in that sense of the word (or in the narrow sense, for that matter). "Tabloid" in the narrow sense merely refers to the way that the physical newspaper is folded, but papers folded in this way came be to associated with a particular style of journalism.
The Telegraph is in the middle of the pack of U.K. news sources in terms of reader trust based upon surveys (see also here). A broader measure of reliability of U.K. news sources that doesn't just rely on survey data ranks the Telegraph in 9th place, which is again, respectable but not a standout.

U.K. newspaper The Telegraph recently published a fabricated article
claiming that whistleblowers informed the newspaper that Hezbollah was
using Beirut International Airport to store a large stockpile of
missiles, which was refuted by local authorities by showing local and
foreign officials along with reporters all divisions of the airport
where there were no such weapons.

The question is, who fabricated the report?
It is entirely possible that the newspaper's sources were providing its reporters with inaccurate information. This happens from time to time and is unavoidable. Alerting readers to the risk that this could happen is one of the reasons that newspaper sources disclose when they rely on whistleblowers or other anonymous sources.
I would not jump to the conclusion that a reporter from the Telegraph simply fabricated a story as the question implies. Indeed, the likelihood that this is true is remote. There have been cases where a reporter at a major reputable new media outlet fabricated a report (and when it has happened, the same reporter has usually fabricate many stories). But, this probably only happens a few times each decade out of scores of stories written every day across scores of media outlets by many hundreds of reporters.
The cases where stories are fabricated by a reporter also rarely involve mundane reporting on foreign military conflicts, like the stories mentioned in the question. Far more often, they involve stories with in depth interviews that generate extremely quotable "perfect" statements from a purported interviewee that are made up, in whole or in part.
It is also sacrosanct among ethical journalists to keep the identity of its informants who provide information subject to a promise of confidentiality secret, even when that information turns out to be wrong. Many excellent journalists have gone to jail to protect these promises.
All newspapers that are not lazy and spineless press release recycling  hubs rely on anonymous sources on a regular basis.
